# Integrate MiniProfiler with .NetCore 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, mvc-mini-profiler, miniprofiler

I want to integrate MiniProfiler is a WebApi or View /XX/results-index.
The WebApi is authenticated with Bearer Tokens. I only want Group Users in Active Directory can see the results, but I don't get it.

I have this code in ServicesCollection:

```
services.AddMiniProfiler(options =>
{
   options.RouteBasePath = "/profiler";
   options.ResultsAuthorizeAsync = async request => await GetAuthorization(request);            }).AddEntityFramework();

private static async Task<bool> GetAuthorization(HttpRequest request)
{
 //   var user = request.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name; --> Is null
   return true;
}
```

In Configure Method in StartUp:

```
app.UseSwagger().UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
   options.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/v1/swagger.json", $"{env.ApplicationName} V1");
   options.OAuthClientId("TestApiswaggerui");
   options.OAuthAppName("TestApi Swagger UI");
   options.IndexStream = () => GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(
                        "TestApi.SwaggerMiniProfiler.html");
})
.UseMiniProfiler();
```

I want to see mini profiler information through some options:

- http://localhost:5050/profiler/results-index --> Show the list methods called
- http://localhost:5050/swagger/index.html --> Show the MiniProfiler in the same page

**Environment:**

```
.NET Core version: 3.1
MiniProfiler version: MiniProfiler.AspNetCore.Mvc v.4.2.1
Operative system: Windows 10
```

Answer (score 0):

The piece you're probably missing here is that MiniProfiler shows *your* results. What's "you" is determined by the `UserIdProvider` option. When recording and viewing profiles, ensure that these are the same "user ID" (defaults to IP address). It looks like this in options:

```
services.AddMiniProfiler(options =>
{
   options.UserIdProvider = request => ConsistentUserId(request);
});
```

If your swagger has zero server-side processing at all (e.g. it does not include the MiniProfiler `<script>` tag from `.RenderInludes()` or the `<mini-profiler />` tag helper, then the issue isn't viewing the profiles so much as not even attempting to view. There are some ideas I have around a static tag *without* profiles to currently view, but I do not know how to get them into Swagger in it's generation phase (just not familiar enough). Note that *it's a blatant hack*, but you could work around the issue at the moment with a manual script tag. You'll want to follow https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/issues/326 for this.

Comment: My problem is that my API, when I publish in the IIS, the authentication is anonymous, since the authentication is done by Bearer Token. If I want to authorize the profiler to put something like User.IsInRole(""), I have to put both authentications, the anonymous one and the Windows one. With this, I solve my problem to open the url http:URL/profiler/results-index

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your comment completely - if your intent is to leave it wide open, you could do so with `options.ResultsAuthorize = request => true;` as an example. See the sample all here for config options: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/main/samples/Samples.AspNetCore3/Startup.cs

Comment: I just want to leave the option of having the traces read for that group from the active directory. I wrote a reply because the page did not leave me because the text was too long.

Comment: @Nacho If you want to change the meaning of a user ID, e.g. translating them to be shared for a group, that's totally doable. You'll want to implement your own `IAsyncStorage`, specifically changing `GetUnviewedIds` which takes the user ID (from the answer above) and decides which IDs to get. You can find all the existing implementations (feel free to copy if needed!) in the MiniProfiler repo: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/

Answer (score 0):

I just want to leave the option of having the traces read for that group from the active directory:

```
 services.AddMiniProfiler(options =>
                    {
                        // (Optional) Path to use for profiler URLs, default is /mini-profiler-resources
                        options.RouteBasePath = "/profiler";

                        options.ColorScheme = StackExchange.Profiling.ColorScheme.Light;
                        options.PopupRenderPosition = StackExchange.Profiling.RenderPosition.BottomLeft;
                        options.PopupShowTimeWithChildren = true;
                        options.PopupShowTrivial = true;
                        options.ShouldProfile = ShowProfile;
                        options.SqlFormatter = new StackExchange.Profiling.SqlFormatters.InlineFormatter();

                        options.ResultsAuthorize = request => request.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("S-INFORMATICA");
 })
                    .AddEntityFramework();
```